# Is it possible to install Solr in Ubuntu Server 18.04 completely from repositories?

Tags: server, 18.04, solr

I'm looking into improving email search speed on my Dovecot server by [integrating with Solr](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS/Solr). On my servers, I try to keep as much of my software as possible installed from the repositories for ease of updating.

I've noticed that there's a `dovecot-solr` package in the repositories, which made me pretty hopeful. There is no `solr` package, but I did see a `solr-common` package that appears to pull in a lot of the Solr prerequisites, including `tomcat-solr` (which pulls in tomcat in full). I installed that.

Now I'm trying to get an impression from the various documentation I've been able to find on where to proceed from there. I see references to accessing "http://myserver:8983/solr" on my server, but it doesn't appear to be accepting connections on that port. Tomcat is running. I've also seen references to a `solr` binary, but I can't find any packages that provide that file.

Is it possible to install Solr completely from repositories? If not, what's the purpose of the `solr-common` package? Does it simplify the outside-repository install at all? If so, is there documentation on how to complete an install of Solr on Ubuntu Server 18.04 starting with what's available in the repositories?